# JS: new window[className] stops execution if prototype not found

Tags: javascript, prototype

Just wondering how to test that a prototype is available based on its name.

For instance:

```
var node = new window[className];   
console.log('test');
```

doesn't print anything if the className provided doesn't match a prototype that's been made available.

So testing:

```
if(! window[className]) {...}
```

make nothing to happen, the execution just stops, no breakpoint available past that point.

How can I handle this case?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you ask for an `else` branch? Which `className` do you test?

Comment: Btw: Javascript has no "classes". And the "prototypes" you search for are called constructor functions, I guess.

Comment: className is for instance "GroundBlock", if there's no prototype name that way, the code just stops. It's using safari, can't test it on other browsers, the code isn't compatible :(

Comment: And you expect "GroundBlock" to exist on the global object? Never heard of such a constructor. And sure, if the condition fails, the code stops because it has reached its end. What else do you think of?

Comment: GroundBlock is a custom prototype. When it's made available, the code goes properly. If not made available/declared, nothing happens, not even an error. By "declared" I mean: "GroundBlock.prototype = new LevelNode();".

Comment: Why do you always talk of "prototypes"? It seems to be a function. And please note that you will first need to define `GroundBlock` before you can set the `prototype` property of it. Post some more code in your question

Comment: Just tested with a try/catch block. That does it; When "className" refers to a constructor that doesn't exist, the caught error says:
message: "'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new window[className]')"

This does it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Huh? If a try-catch works to solve your problem, your code **threw an error** - why didn't you see that?

Comment: Didn't appear, even when activating the "stop on all errors". Restarted safari, cleared cache, etc. but can't get it to "see" the error. Weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen when `className` is not available, just use a [simple `else` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

```
if(! window[className]) {
   ...
} else {
   alert("No truthy property '"+className+"' was found on the window object");
   throw new Error("something bad happened");
   // whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that a missing property (in my case?) can be handled through a try/catch statement. If/else didn't help. this does it!

Comment: Your if-statement checks only for the `className` thing, nothing further. However, you should never "test" on properties with try-catch-statements.

Comment: Feels like a last resort solution in this case :(